# Nero Wolfe novel in which Wolfe describes a perfect, unprepared crime

Tags: identification-request, mystery-novels, rex-stout

I read (long ago!) a Rex Stout / Nero Wolfe novel in which Nero Wolfe describes what he thinks would be the perfect crime (i.e., a crime performed without any preparation just taking advantage of circunstances). I cannot find in which book. Can you?

Comment: Is there anything else you can remember from that book?

Comment: Not much I'm afraid. As in all books in the series, Nero Wolfe is just home, eaing and drinking. This is one of the rare occasions in which Nero states a ''philisophical'' comment about what could be a perfect crime.

Comment: I also remember that I read the book in French, but most of Stout's books were translated into French.